# open new view controller from view with scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

i'm developing an iphone app with scrollable tab in the initial view, with 4 pages. i have a view, BaseViewController,  with only a scroll view on the bottom that contain 4 button.
On viewDidLoad{} i set dimensions of page and method for call the pages with button or with swipe.

Now, from the first page i want to open a new view with back button but without scroll view on the bottom. if i use push, scroll view still be on the bottom and if i use modal there isn't back button on the top.

i've tried a lot of solutions on web but no one work correctly.

```
//#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BaseViewController.h"
#import "FirstTabController.h"
#import "SecondTabController.h"
#import "ThirdTabController.h"
#import "FourthTabBarController.h"

@interface BaseViewController (){
    NSInteger indicator;
    //AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

@end

@implementation BaseViewController;
@synthesize tabBarScroller, storyBoard;
@synthesize firstTab, secondTab, thirdTab, fourthTab;
@synthesize btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setup];

    //appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //appDelegate.base=self;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
}

-(void)slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if (indicator!=1) {
        [self tabCall:indicator-1];
    }
}

 -(void)slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer    *)gestureRecognizer{
    if (indicator!=4) {
        [self tabCall:indicator+1];
    }
}

-(void)setup {
    [tabBarScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(519, 49)];

    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard    storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iphone_small" bundle:nil];
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 431);
    }else{
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard     storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iphone_large" bundle:nil];
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 519);
    }

    [self tabCall:1];
    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor]; 
    btn3.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    btn4.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}

-(IBAction)buttonTabClicked:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [self tabCall:button.tag];
}

-(void)tabCall:(NSInteger)tag {
    indicator=tag;

     switch (tag) {
        case 1:
            [tabBarScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
            [self.view addSubview:self.navFirstTab.view];
            btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn3.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn4.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 2:
            [tabBarScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(30,0) animated:YES];
            [self.view addSubview:self.navSecondTab.view];
            btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            btn3.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn4.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 3:
            [tabBarScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(160,0) animated:YES];
            [self.view addSubview:self.navThirdTab.view];
            btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn3.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            btn4.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 4:
            [tabBarScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(199,0) animated:YES];
            [self.view addSubview:self.navFourthTab.view];
            btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn3.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            btn4.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (UINavigationController*) navFirstTab
{
    if (!_navFirstTab) {
        if (!firstTab) {
            firstTab = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTabController"];
        }
        _navFirstTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.firstTab];
        _navFirstTab.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _navFirstTab.view.frame = rect;
        _navFirstTab.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"First Controller";
    }
    return _navFirstTab;
}


- (UINavigationController*) navSecondTab
{
    if (!_navSecondTab) {
        if (!secondTab) {
            secondTab = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondTabController"];
        }
        _navSecondTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.secondTab];
        _navSecondTab.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _navSecondTab.view.frame = rect;
        _navSecondTab.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Second Controller";
    }
    return _navSecondTab;
}

- (UINavigationController*) navThirdTab
{
    if (!_navThirdTab) {
        if (!thirdTab) {
            thirdTab = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdTabController"];
        }
        _navThirdTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.thirdTab];
        _navThirdTab.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _navThirdTab.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Third Controller";
        _navThirdTab.view.frame = rect;
    }
    return _navThirdTab;
}
- (UINavigationController*) navFourthTab
{
    if (!_navFourthTab) {
        if (!fourthTab) {
             fourthTab = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FourthTabBarController"];
         }
         _navFourthTab = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:self.fourthTab];
         _navFourthTab.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
         _navFourthTab.view.frame = rect;
         _navFourthTab.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Fourth Controller";
    }
    return _navFourthTab;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add/remove viewControllers as subviews for each button click instead of pushing or presenting.You can have more control on items displaying on rootView Controller.